# I'm trying to get my CSS working locally again

Tags: html, css

I can't get my CSS to be rendered locally. It was up before and I'm wondering if it is the order in which it appears in the head tag or if I am simply using the wrong path.

I've tried changing the order and different file paths including:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"> (this one I thought should work but doesn't).
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SoundOff</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.1/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
          family=Poppins:300,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
          family=Montserrat:900|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- <!All fonts-->
    <link href="http://allfont.net/allfont.css?fonts=antonio-bold" 
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" 
          integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" 
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="canonical" 
          href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sign-in/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What do you see in dev tools?

Comment: Did you check if the `styles.css` file is inside a folder named `/css`? Is the file name correct? Remember that the referenced folder that you're pointing is relative to the your `.html` file.